# Local override for {gem} at /path/to/local/git/repo is using branch develop but Gemfile specifies develop

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, rubygems, bundler

I'm running bundler v1.3.0.pre.2 and trying to get bundler to bundle a local git repository holding a gem, into a rails app.

Gemfile :

```
gem 'mygem', :github => 'myrepo/mygem', :branch => 'develop'
```

Config :

```
bundle config local.mygem /path/to/local/git/repo
```

Bundle install throws the error :

> Local override for mygem at /path/to/local/git/repo is using branch
>   develop but Gemfile specifies develop

Is this a bug ? I see that the branch names are exactly the same. What could be wrong ? Got the same error for Bundler v1.2.3 as well

Answer (score 10):

You can use a local gem and even the branch you are working on like this

```
gem 'rspec-rails', path: '~/forks/rspec-rails', branch: 'feature-branch'
```

Just change `github` to `path`, Then

```
bundle install
```

Also as far as bundler config goes, although it is in the docs, I have never needed to change the local config like you did above.

With this method I have never needed to remove `Gemfile.lock`, it just picks up the changes to your local repo.

Although I don't recommend it, you could disable the branch checking feature used by bundler to make sure you are using the correct branch when developing

```
bundle config disable_local_branch_check true
```

Comment: Thank you - disabling the branch checking is a godsend when working with lots of short-lived topic branches.

Answer (score 7):

If you just need to point to a branch within a local repository you're using like a gem, in gemfile:

```
gem 'gem-name', :path=> 'relative/path/to/directory'
```

Then create bundler configuration for that "gem" before `bundle`-ing

<sup>(Keep in mind the repository name may be different than the gem's name, although this is not the norm).</sup>

```
bundle config local.repository-name relative/path/to/directory
```

Magically, whatever branch is currently checked out locally will be active when you start a local server. You'll likely need to restart your server if you need to make changes or change branches (unless you have some type of automatic reloading feature).

One gotcha is when a configuration setting is already established (let's say via the mechanism above), and you need to use/reference a remote git gem - you don't need bundler configuration to use a remote git gem (if you have an active configuration, you'll get the `local override` error).

Check to make sure you don't have local settings for given gem:

```
bundle config local.gem-name
```

If you do, remove configuration for that gem:

```
bundle config --delete local.gem-name
```

Then point to remote repo and branch, in gemfile:

```
gem 'gem-name', :path => 'https://github.com/reponame.git', :branch => 'branch_name'
```

More information:

Git Gems: http://bundler.io/v1.7/git.html

"bundle config": http://bundler.io/v1.7/man/bundle-config.1.html

Comment: major +1 for including reversal notes

Comment: "Magically, whatever branch is currently checked out locally will be active" - Exactly what I was looking for, thanks, and it works great. (Other information I found seemed to indicate this wasn't possible, so I was pushing to GH and referencing the branch remotely there.)

Answer (score 2):

This [GitHub issue](https://github.com/carlhuda/bundler/issues/1957) suggests that the workaround may be to remove `Gemfile.lock` and do `bundle install` again.

Answer (score 2):

The branch you reference in your Gemfile needs to be the same as you have checked out in the local repository.  Note that after you commit in the local repository you will need to run bundle install on your main application so that it rebuilds the Gemfile.lock to include the new revision hash and commit it.  I recommend using the gem below as it automates this process for you and also aids in other scenarios.  See the gem page for exact detail.

https://github.com/EPI-USE-Labs/git-bundle

**Full detail of what happens:**

When you use a git repository in your gemfile you can use [bundle local overrides for development](http://bundler.io/v1.5/git.html#local) which will store revision hashes in your Gemfile.lock.  On production these exact revision hashes will be checked out when it runs bundle install.

**Gemfile:**

`gem 'example', git: 'https://github.com/your_name/example.git', branch: :master`

**Bundle config shell command:**

`bundle config local.example /path/to/local/git/repository`

**Gemfile.lock (auto generated):**

`GIT
  remote: https://github.com/your_name/example.git
  revision: b9270e61abb89e1ff77fb8cfacb463e4d04388ad
  branch: master`